# LoadKeyboardLayout() fails to change Keyboard Layout if the Windows Taskbar has current focus

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, keyboard, sendmessage

I am changing the Keyboard Layout in Windows programmatically with global hot keys using:

```
IntPtr fGWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
SendMessage(fGWindow.ToInt32(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST_as_unit, IntPtr.Zero, LoadKeyboardLayout(LANG, KLF_SUBSTITUTE_OK));
```

The code works perfectly except when I click the Windows Taskbar using the mouse (giving it current focus). In that situation, the message is sent but `LoadKeyboardLayout()` does noting.

Using `HWND_BROADCAST` instead of `GetForegroundWindow()` does not help.

**UPDATE / More information:**

The pointer obtained by `GetForegroundWindow()` when I click the taskbar (giving it focus) belongs to `explorer.exe`. In that situation the code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, basically adjustments are needed if the current foreground window is the system tray:

```
IntPtr shell_TrayWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);

if (fGWindow == shell_TrayWnd)
 {
   IntPtr vHandle = FindWindow("Progman", "Program Manager"); // Desktop Handler.
   SetForegroundWindow(vHandle);
   SendMessage(vHandle.ToInt32(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST_as_unit, new IntPtr(-1), LoadKeyboardLayout(LANG, KLF_NOTELLSHELL));
}
```